# Optimizing delete query by order

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

We have a big DB with a lot of data, each row consists of several columns, one is a value and another is time.
The table is ordered by time.
We want to use a DELETE query to delete all the rows where value is in some range:

```
    DELETE FROM sometable
WHERE ( value > 80 AND value < 90);
```

The problem is this query takes a lot of time on the servers and we want to optimize this.
We do know that all the rows we want to delete is with some known time value.
Is there a way to use the fact that the table is ordered by time to optimized the query and reduce time on the server?

for example, on the following table:

[image]

There is no need for the server to "check" rows 1-3 and 10-end, if we know that all the rows we want to delete is with time 2/1/2015

Thank you.

EDIT:
we are using Microsoft SQL server 2019

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: _all the rows we want to delete is with some known time value_ If you have a useful index on that column, then just include the appropriate condition in the WHERE clause. But all anyone can do is guess if you do not provide DDL. Note - use date constants that are not ambiguous and that do not depend on runtime settings to be interpreted correctly. (e.g., '20150201` assuming you mean Februrary 1)

Comment: If you know all the rows to be deleted are for time '2/1/2015', add that to your `WHERE` clause. Note than a table is logically an unordered set of rows but, with a clustered index on time, that index controls physical ordering and can be leveraged to optimize the delete operation.

Comment: If you are deleting most of the rows in the table, it's probably quicker to dump into a new table and switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, deleting a bunch of rows takes time.  There is a lot of overhead for removing rows -- particularly logging and locking, but maintaining indexes, triggers, and foreign keys also adds overhead.

The most common technique for handling this uses table partitions.  Basically, the table is stored in separate pieces, in this case by time -- say one piece per week or per month.  The database handles the partitioning to make it efficient.

Then, deleting the rows from a particular period is simply a matter of dropping a partition.  This is usually much, much, much faster than deleting the records.

This does require re-constructing the table (a one-time cost).  The exact syntax and details depends on the database you are using.  But this should point you in a direction to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, if I understand you correctly, this method will delete all rows where the the time column is in some range. I want to delete only the rows where the value column is in some range and not all the data in this time range.

Comment: @YakirShlezinger . . . You can actually partition by any columns, including value.  That said, time partitions are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the table I assume that the first column is a primary key. Use the key to delete records. See example below.

The ... in (select id from some table where value > 80 AND value < 90) gets the keys to be deleted.

The full query looks like this:
delete from sometable
where id in (select id from some table where value > 80 AND value < 90);